# Java Simple number game App crashes when EditText is empty

Tags: java, android

I have made a simple Android app, where the app creates a number between 1 and 20 and the user has to guess it.
Everything works fine, except one thing: When I let the `EditText` empty, the App crashes instantly when I press the Button. How can I prevent that? I tried an `if-else` Argument at the point where the entered Text of the `EditText` is given to the global created `editText` Variable `editTextGuess`, but then the app crashed instantly after launch.

What do I have to Code, that the app does not crash caused by the empty textfield but creates a toast saying "Oops, your Textfield is empty"?

```
package com.example.randomness;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Den EditText und den Integer für die zufällige Zahl global erstellen
    EditText editTextGuess;
    int RandomNumber;

    //Hier einen Void eröffnen, um die zufällige Zahl zu erstellen
    public void generateRandomNumber(){
        Random random = new Random();

        RandomNumber = random.nextInt(20) +1;
    }

    //Erstellen der OnClick Methode für den Button, View view ist wichtig!
    public void guess(View view){
        Log.i("Button clicked", "Worked!");

        int guessValue;
        guessValue = Integer.parseInt(editTextGuess.getText().toString());
        Log.i("Entered Value:", Integer.toString(guessValue));
        Log.i("The random number is:", Integer.toString(RandomNumber));


        String message;

        if(guessValue > RandomNumber){
            message = "Your guessed number is too high!";
        } else if(guessValue < RandomNumber){
            message = "Your guessed number is too low!";
        } else if(guessValue == RandomNumber){
            message = "You were right! Let's play again!";
            generateRandomNumber();
            Log.i("Info", "New random number created");
        } else {
            message = "Something went wrong...";
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextGuess = findViewById(R.id.editTextRaten);
        generateRandomNumber();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your edit text string value before assigning it to the variable.

```
public void guess(View view){
    Log.i("Button clicked", "Worked!");

    int guessValue;
    if(!editTextGuess.getText().toString().equals("")){
        guessValue = Integer.parseInt(editTextGuess.getText().toString());
        Log.i("Entered Value:", Integer.toString(guessValue));
        Log.i("The random number is:", Integer.toString(RandomNumber));


        String message;

        if(guessValue > RandomNumber){
            message = "Your guessed number is too high!";
        } else if(guessValue < RandomNumber){
            message = "Your guessed number is too low!";
        } else if(guessValue == RandomNumber){
            message = "You were right! Let's play again!";
            generateRandomNumber();
            Log.i("Info", "New random number created");
        } else {
            message = "Something went wrong...";
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }  else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Oops, your Textfield is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect, It worked!

I changed your `if(!editTextGuess.getText().toString().equals("")){` to `if(editTextGuess.getText().toString().length() > 0){` but you really helped me!

Comment: `editTextGuess.getText().toString().length()` will return 1 if you enter a blank space in EditText. So I will suggest the `!equals("")` approach.

Comment: I used a just-numbers editText, so you can not enter black spaces. But thanks for your answer, I will keep that in mind for future!

Answer (score 2):

Before you try to use text from `EditText`, check if it contains any text or not. If it does, read the text otherwise display a `toast`

```
String text = editTextGuess.getText().toString().trim();

if(text.length == 0) {
  // show toast
} else {
  // use text from  editTextGuess
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because `parseInt()` throws a `NumberFormatException` when it tries to parse an empty string.

How to fix this depends on what you want if the input field is empty.

```
String value = editTextGuess.getText().toString();
if (!value.isEmpty()) {
    guessValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
    ...
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Oops, input field is empty", ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the issue has already been pointed out by @Yousaf [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604878/java-simple-number-game-app-crashes-when-textfield-is-empty/54604919#54604919) that will help you move forward but would like to add few things to take care in future to help debugging easier:
Always try to create multiple statements where you are dereferencing object like

```
guessValue = Integer.parseInt(editTextGuess.getText().toString());
```

can be written as

```
String text=editTextGuess.getText().toString();
guessValue = Integer.parseInt(text);
```

It will help you know the exact cause of failure.Like you may encounter `NumberFormatException` if the entered string is not number.